# Why is the first type parameter better than the second?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, type-parameter

I was going through TS documentation when I came across the section [Use Fewer Type Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#use-fewer-type-parameters). Here, we are presented with 2 examples:

```
function filter1<Type>(arr: Type[], func: (arg: Type) => boolean): Type[] {
  return arr.filter(func);
}
```

```
function filter2<Type, Func extends (arg: Type) => boolean>(
  arr: Type[],
  func: Func
): Type[] {
  return arr.filter(func);
}
```

According to the description the 1st one is said to be better compared to the 2nd. Although the 2nd has more code, I do not particularly see how it is worse. I do see that `Func` is being used similar to a type definition but that is it.

If anyone could particularly tell me what the statement

> callers wanting to specify type arguments have to manually specify an extra type argument

from the description means, it would be massively helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A caller of a function might want to explicitly provide type parameters when calling a function. Since TypeScript [does not have partial type inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), *every* type parameter would have to be provided.

---

Let's look at an example:

Say you have a function which takes only `'a' | 'b'` as its argument.

```
function takesOnlyAB(arg: 'a' | 'b') { return true }
```

And you want to call it within your `filter` callback.

```
filter1(["a", "b"], (arg) => takesOnlyAB(arg)) 
//                                       ^^^ Argument of type 'string'  
//                                           is not assignable to parameter of type
//                                           '"a" | "b"'
```

You would run into this annoying error. There are multiple ways to fix it. One would be to provide the type parameter of `Type` explictly.

```
// works fine
filter1<'a' | 'b'>(["a", "b"], (arg) => takesOnlyAB(arg))
```

With `filter2`, you would have to provide *both* type parameters.

```
filter2<'a' | 'b', (arg: 'a' | 'b') => boolean>(
  ["a", "b"], 
  (arg) => takesOnlyAB(arg)
)
```

You can see that it is unnecessary effort to type out both type parameters when one would have been enough.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAbKBTATgRgDwAqAngA4YB8AFAIZZYBcixZA2gLoA0y4EjNWAc0bMMASkQBecogBGcOKgzUwo4aQztEAbwBQiRFgxQQWJLSwA6FOmyVQkUQG4dAXx0770eEmuYsAJkJ1LgAxHkQMAA9MMAATAGdEfiEmdXEpWXlFZSo9RHM1Vk48z0YwyB1VVKLtPMNjU3y6KzQ-Ox4nV3dPWAREKGoAawx4gHkwVCIAQQAhZMYAcmoFxAAfRAWZBfEtAyMTJCgsEAxENw9W7BxKFgAialuuW5lbziTaAXTpAeGxiem5h9ROIdAB6UH6SFQ6Ew2FwqEAPSRiCmghAAFsMGAoIg4MB+uoNvEjjAwAIVjBEmA4DiwRD4QzGUzqPF4jABGBqDJFP04IgSLRqJi-Lj8VBCQt7rc1ohnrcFt1Lrg8EsVutNgsqHcHk8Xm9kl9+kMRuNJrMDSCLjYAirljKNVx5hs7eqtoa5AolGAtVLda9HUDJN9jX8zYDBMDEEA)

Comment: Aaah - thanks for the explanation and especially the example. This definitely helps me understand better.